# Remove Salesforce styling only from buttons in VF page

Tags: visualforce, css, bootstrap

I've added a button to my visualforce page, and have added the bootstrap class btn success to it.

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>`

However, Salesforce adds styling to buttons which results in the button being styled incorrectly, I can override this behaviour by putting  standardStylesheets="false" in the `<apex:page>` tag, but this is much too extreme and would require lots of fiddling to fix the rest of my page.

Is there a way I can remove just the styling Salesforce provide for the buttons, via CSS?

Comment: Did you add bootstrap css file?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Yes, and other bootstrap elements display correctly. It just seems to be elements which Salesforce applies its own styling to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568065), you can fork the [Bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap), then modify the bootstrap.less file to include an outer scope:

```
#bootstrap-scope {
    // All remaining code here
}
```

Run make in order to rebuild the CSS, upload that as your static resource, and finally, scope your page's content with a wrapper:

```
<div id="bootstrap-scope">
    <!-- more code here -->
    <button class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
</div>
```

Because of the specificity rules of CSS, any button inside the bootstrap-scope element should match the Bootstrap CSS instead of the salesforce CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can. For that you will have to "overwrite" the ".btn" class of Salesforce CSS with a CSS of Bootstrap. Just put all Bootstrap ".btn" class definitions to the top of the visualforce page directly:

```
<style>
.btn {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:6px 12px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:1.42857143;
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -ms-touch-action:manipulation;
    touch-action:manipulation;
    cursor:pointer;-webkit-user-select:none;
    ... 
}
</style>
```

The page will then take this style for all "btn" elements on the page.

But first I would try to add the Bootstrap's CSS file to the page, but I am not sure whether all "btn" elements are in Bootstrap style then...

Comment: I would highly suggest downloading bootstrap's source and changing `btn` to `btn-bootstrap` then re-compile and upload the new css file. This keeps you from having to override the SFDC styles.